# How can I use WGET to get only status info and save it somewhere?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

can I use WGET to get, let's say, status 200 OK and save that status somewhere? If not, how can I do that using ubuntu linux?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With curl you can

```sh
curl -L -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" http://google.com >> status.txt
```

Comment: can I get more than just status? Like if there is an error, what is it?

Comment: yes, `-w "%{http_code} %{errormsg}\n"`

Answer (score 2):

You use `--save-headers` to add the headers to the output, put the output to the console using `-O -`, ignore the errors stream using `>/dev/null` and get only the status line using `grep HTTP/`.

You can then output that into a file using `>status_file`

```
$ wget --save-headers -O - http://google.com/ 2>/dev/null | grep HTTP/ > status_file
```

Answer (score 2):

The question suggests that **the output of the wget command be stored somewhere**. As another alternative, the following example shows how to store the output of wget execution in a shell variable (**wget_status**). Where after the execution of the wget command the status of the execution is stored in the variable **wget_status**. The wget status is displayed in the console using the echo command.

```
$ wget_status=$(wget --server-response ${URL} 2>&1 | awk '/^  HTTP/{print $2}')
$ echo $wget_status
200
```

After the execution of the wget command, the execution status can be manipulated using the value of the **wget_status** variable.

For more information consult the following link as a reference:

https://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/148595-capture-http-response-code-wget.html

The tests were executed using cloudshell on a linux system.

Linux cs-335831867014-default 5.10.90+ #1 SMP Wed Mar 23 09:10:07 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux